# GitHub newbie: Branches or separate repos for similar code? What works best?

Tags: git, github

I'm new to GitHub but I recently started to use it to manage HTML/CSS for the forum websites I look after.
I have a total of 15 forums and the core HTML/CSS is basically the same in all of them, except for a few differences.
Any changes to the core part of the code should be for all the forums while retaining the individual bits for each forum. 
What would be a best practice to manage them? A repo for each individual forum or  branches? I want to make sure I use GitHub as effectively as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Branches is the way to go so if you need to change core files you will be able to merge it with other "sub" projects. You can see a brief overview of the workflow here https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/